# how to query from mysql to get solution of the following?

Tags: mysql, database

how to query for

```
SL  STATUS    DATETIME
1   STOP      2012-12-19 13:10:00    
2   STOP      2012-12-19 13:12:00       
3   STOP      2012-12-19 13:14:00   
4   STOP      2012-12-19 13:16:00   
5   STOP      2012-12-19 13:18:00    
6   STOP      2012-12-19 13:20:00
7   START     2012-12-19 13:22:00
```

from table mysql query as

```
SL  STATUS    DATETIME                   STOPPAGE
1   STOP      2012-12-19 13:10:00        00:10
2   START     2012-12-19 13:22:00
```

I have to get the difference between the values of date as **STOPPAGE** where the status is **STOP**

Comment: Yes i have tried! but have to get the Output of stoppage...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) GROUP BY STATUS)
```

This will give you following

```
SL  STATUS    DATETIME                   
1   STOP      2012-12-19 13:10:00        
2   START     2012-12-19 13:22:00
```

Comment: This won't give `SL` values of 1, 2

Comment: I have to get the difference between the values of date as **STOPPAGE** where the status is **STOP**

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sl,status,min(DATETIME) FROM   GROUP BY STATUS

Comment: Yes but i have to get the stoppage(which is the output of last stop - first stop)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly how you are choosing the values that you wish to select for `SL` and `DATETIME` in the resultset (especially if there is are multiple records with the same `DATETIME` value), but assuming that they are those of the record with the earliest `DATETIME` in a run of unchanging `STATUS`:

```
SELECT my_table.*, t.STOPPAGE
FROM   my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   STATUS,
           MIN(DATETIME) AS DATETIME,
           NULLIF(TIMEDIFF(MAX(DATETIME),MIN(DATETIME)),0) AS STOPPAGE
  FROM (
    SELECT   t1.DATETIME, t1.STATUS, MIN(t2.DATETIME) AS next
    FROM     my_table t1 LEFT JOIN my_table t2
          ON t1.DATETIME < t2.DATETIME AND t1.STATUS <> t2.STATUS
    GROUP BY t1.DATETIME, t1.STATUS
  ) t
  GROUP BY next
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d043a/3/0).

If you don't need `SL` in the resultset (or it should be an incrementing counter), you can omit the outermost query:

```
SELECT   @sl := @sl + 1 AS SL,
         STATUS,
         MIN(DATETIME) AS DATETIME,
         NULLIF(TIMEDIFF(MAX(DATETIME),MIN(DATETIME)),0) AS STOPPAGE
FROM (
  SELECT   t1.DATETIME, t1.STATUS, MIN(t2.DATETIME) AS next
  FROM     my_table t1 LEFT JOIN my_table t2
        ON t1.DATETIME < t2.DATETIME AND t1.STATUS <> t2.STATUS
  GROUP BY t1.DATETIME, t1.STATUS
) t, (SELECT @sl := 0) init
GROUP BY next
ORDER BY DATETIME
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d043a/5/0).